# How current_user works in devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise

I have been using the [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authenticating my rails app for some time now, and I just began to wonder how the `current_user` works

How does [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) saves the current_user?

- Browser session?
- Application session?
- Some other parts of the Application?

I am suspecting that the answer is number one `Browser session`. Reason being that even when an app gets restarted, and you try to access the app again from a browser that has been used to sign in already, it automatically signs you in.

My confusion though is this: If it is the browser session, it means that when the browser relaunches ( the session was ended ) `current_user` should be expired, and the user signed out; but it does not work so.

So, how does the `current_user` operates? thanks for all contributions.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` works by storing id of current user in the application session. Most commonly session is stored in cookies. Whether or not the cookies survive browser restart depends on client's browser settings.

Comment: So, are you saying that it gets stored in the **browser** session?

Comment: Nope, application session. Or maybe it depends on what exactly you mean by these two terms.

Comment: @SunnyK: by the way, last time I checked, devise was open source. So it's easy to know _exactly_ what it does there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have clicked `remember_me` it stores a signed token unique to user in a permanent cookie and stores it in browser. It is saved in database also.

When current_user is called again , rails checks if the permanent cookie exists, if so compares it with the one in database. If they are the same , you are logged in as that user.